# Create a table out of tasks grouped by enum

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, enums

I have this model in Entity Framework MVC 5 app:

```
public class Task
{
    public int ID {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public TaskStatus Status {get;set;}
}

 public enum TaskStatus
    {
        ToDo = 0,
        InProgress = 1,
        InTesting = 2,
        Done = 3
    }
```

Out of it, I want to create a view which will be a table where various tasks will be grouped by their TaskStatus, with each task status as a table column and some attributes as items for that column. So far I've succeeded in grouping the items:

```
// suppose a,b,c,d,e are Task objects
var list = new List<Task> { a,b,c,d,e };
var groupedList = list.GroupBy(l => l.Status);
```

This produced enumerable I can loop through and get the key + all the values. But how do I actually put them in a table (create a table using Razor/view logic)? Any help would be appreciated (as well as if you have an easier way to do this by NOT using GroupBy to first group the items by status, taking a whole another approach).

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way is to group at server side.

### Model

```
public class TaskGroup
{
    public TaskStatus Status { get; set; }
    public IList<Task> Tasks { get; set; }

    public TaskGroup()
    {
        Tasks = new List<Task>();
    }
}

public class Task
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public TaskStatus Status { get; set; }
}

public enum TaskStatus
{
    ToDo = 0,
    InProgress = 1,
    InTesting = 2,
    Done = 3
}
```

### Controller

```
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var tasks = new List<Task>
        {
            new Task { ID = 1, Name = "One", Status = TaskStatus.ToDo},
            new Task { ID = 2, Name = "Two", Status = TaskStatus.InProgress},
            new Task { ID = 3, Name = "Three", Status = TaskStatus.InTesting},
            new Task { ID = 4, Name = "Four", Status = TaskStatus.Done},
            new Task { ID = 5, Name = "Five", Status = TaskStatus.ToDo},
            new Task { ID = 6, Name = "Six", Status = TaskStatus.InProgress}
        };

        var model = tasks.GroupBy(t => t.Status, t => t)
            .Select(g => new TaskGroup {Status = g.Key, Tasks = g as IList<Task>})
            .ToList();

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

### View

```
@model IList<DemoMvc.Models.TaskGroup>
@{
    Layout = null;
}

<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <title>Index</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <table class="table table-bordered" width="200">
            @foreach (var item in Model)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        @item.Status
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <table class="table table-bordered">
                            <thead>
                                <tr>
                                    <th>ID</th>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                </tr>
                            </thead>
                            @foreach (var task in item.Tasks)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>@task.ID</td>
                                    <td>@task.Name</td>
                                </tr>
                            }
                        </table>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            }
        </table>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

### Output

[image]

Another method is to use the control like [Telerik Kendo Grid](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/index) in which you do not need to do anything at server side.

Comment: Thanks. Is there similar to Kendo Grid that allows you to do drag-and-drop of tasks? Something like Trello does, basically have these tasks in 4 separate columns and drag and drop each between a column to change task's status from 'todo' to 'complete' etc.

Comment: They might have written from ground up by themselves. I believe [http://gridster.net/](http://gridster.net/) might be a little bit close to it. If you create a separate question, you might get more answer.